# Formatting word pages using MSO style prefixes

Tags: html, css, ms-word, asp-classic

> I need to pre-format an MS page. Particularly fonts so that they are consistent with a website.
>   MS seems to ignore at the very least the font-family MSO styles set.

I have already tried `!important` and saving the word document as a web page, editing styles and using those in the original HTML file I'm trying to format on the word page.

My code:

```
<style>
h1 {
    font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif!important;
    mso-fareast-font-family:"Trebuchet MS"!important;
    }

p { 
    font-family:"Arial",Helvetica,sans-serif!important;
    mso-fareast-font-family:"Arial"!important;
  }
</style>

<%
  Dim file
  file = "saveddocument.doc"

  With Response
        .Buffer = True
        .ContentType = "application/msword"
        .AddHeader "content-disposition", "inline; filename=" & file
        .Write "<h1>This text should be formatted as Trebuchet MS</h1>" _
             & "<p> This text should be formatted as Arial</p>"

        .Flush
        .End
  End With
%>
```

Expected Results:

> When MS Word is opened the `h1` headings should be styled with the font
>   Trebuchet MS and the `p` tags with Arial.

Current result:

> Defaulting to Times New Roman

What am I missing? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this for me goes as follows:

```
    Response.ContentType = "application/msword"
    Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=HelpFile.doc" 
    Response.write("<html " & _ 
        "xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' " & _
        "xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word'" & _ 
        "xmlns='https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/'>")
```

The `xmlns` code in particular was missing from my code and thus was unable to read the `css`.

Adding this into the document ensured that it was readable and fixed my font formatting issues. I hope this answer can help others in a similar situation in the future.